# Sass - a way to invert Lighten/Darken function by variable?

Tags: sass

I'm trying to think of a simple way to invert the darken/lighten color function using a variable. Something like so...

```
$invert_switch: off;
```

And...

```
@if $invert_switch == "on" {
    darken == lighten
    lighten == darken
} @else {
    darken == darken
    lighten == lighten
}
```

I know that's not proper code, I'm just trying to explain it very simply.

If this was used...

```
background: darken($bg, 10%);
color: lighten($txt, 50%);
```

How could I flip that, so it would be...

```
background: lighten($bg, 10%);
color: darken($txt, 50%);
```

Or maybe there is an easier way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I try to change the name of the functions `darken` and `lighten` but I can't. The problem I have found is that SASS haven't something like `@break` or `@continue` to exit for the function and do nothing, my idea was the following code but when the custom fuction coincides with the SASS function goes to a infinite loop:

```
$invert_switch: on;

@function darken($color, $amount){
  @if $invert_switch == on {
    @return lighten($color, $amount);
  }
  @else {
    @return darken($color, $amount);
  }
}

@function lighten($color, $amount){
  @if $invert_switch == on {
    @return darken($color, $amount);
  }
  @else {
    @return lighten($color, $amount);
  }
}


h1{
  color: darken(red, 10%);
}

p{
  color: lighten(red, 10%);
}
```

I change the name of the functions adding a underscore to work:

```
$invert_switch: on;

@function _darken($color, $amount){
  @if $invert_switch == on {
    @return lighten($color, $amount);
  }
  @else {
    @return darken($color, $amount);
  }
}

@function _lighten($color, $amount){
  @if $invert_switch == on {
    @return darken($color, $amount);
  }
  @else {
    @return lighten($color, $amount);
  }
}


h1{
  color: _darken(red, 10%);
}

p{
  color: _lighten(red, 10%);
}
```

Maybe someone can improve this code using the proper names of functions